# Flexbox: move middle element to the next line

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a `flex` item that has three `divs` inside of it.

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────┐
|                WRAPPER                 |
|   ┌─────────┬───────────┬──────────┐   |
|   |  LEFT   |   CENTER  |   RIGHT  |   |
|   |         |           |          |   |
|   └─────────┴───────────┴──────────┘   |
└────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

And I want to move the `center` column to the next line in small screens (less than 600px). It should occupy the 100% of the width of the screen.

The problem I have is that when the `center` column comes to the next line, the `right` column does not fit on the wrapper.

Here is my `HTML` code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="block left">Left</div>
    <div class="block center">Center</div>
    <div class="block right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Here is my `CSS` code:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.block{
  height: 50px;
}

.left{
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  order: 1;
}

.center{
  width: 60%;
  background-color: green;
  order: 2;
}

.right{
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  order: 3;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  #wrapper{
    flex-flow:column wrap; 
    height: 100px;
  }
  .center {
    width: 100%;
    order: 3;
  }

  .left{
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqLezyfe/) where you can see how it is displayed.

Is it possible to move the middle column to the next line occupying 100% of the width of the screen using `flexbox`? If it is, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/wqLezyfe/2/

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  #wrapper{
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .center {
    width: 100%;
    order: 3;
  }

  .left{
    width: 50%;
  }
  .right{
    width:50%;
    order:2;

  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah! Exactly this! So it seems that the problem was that I have to use `flex-wrap: wrap` instead of `column wrap`. Right?

Comment: yep! that was the problem :-P

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on your question please? I suppose it is because wrap makes the overflow element comes down and the `column-wrap` just displays them as a column. Am I right?

Comment: well that column-wrap was incorrect because you wanted to use rows, I know it sounds weird but that's how display flex works, you can take a look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ where it explains the flex-direction property properly.

Answer (score 7):

This was nearly what I needed, but not quite. My issue was that I have a collection of settings, all of which have a label, a selected option and a button. When there's not space for all 3 of them I need the option to wrap to the next line. As the labels and options can be a huge variety of values and combinations I need the solution to react to the length of the text. I also really want it to only wrap when it's necessary. The point of responsive is to make it better for smaller screens, not have them scrolling all the time!

The solution I found was to wrap the first 2 items in an inner wrapper with `flex-direction: row;` so that when it wraps the items will stack vertically. Then the inner wrapper and the buttons need to be denied wrapping with `flex-wrap: nowrap;` so they will always align horizontally.

The result is 3 items on a row, and the middle one wraps.

**Alt 1**
If you need the 1st item to be the one that takes up all the remaining space, just move `flex-grow: 1;` to the `.left`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: top;
  text-align: center;
  
  outline: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.block {
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
}

.center {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em;
}
label:has( #embiggen:checked ) ~ div#wrapper #centerDiv {
    min-width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="block left">LeftLeftLeft</div>
    <div class="block center" id="centerDiv">CenterCenterCenter</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block right">RightRightRight</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/es8u4e7L/)

**Alt 2**
If you need the middle item to wrap beneath the `.right` item, which is the button in my case, then you need to put the `.center` and `.right` items in the `inner-wrapper` instead and in reverse order. To overcome the reversing of the order we need to add `flex-direction: row-reverse` to the `inner-wrapper`, and you need to give the `.right` class a `margin-left: auto;` so that it sits over to the right.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: top;
  text-align: center;

  outline: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.block {
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
}

.center {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em;
}
label:has( #embiggen:checked ) ~ div#wrapper #centerDiv {
    min-width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block left">LeftLeftLeft</div>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="block right">RightRightRight</div>
    <div class="block center" id="centerDiv">CenterCenterCenter</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Right-align JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tefpzjyv/3/)

Comment: plus 1! this is pure genius!

Comment: In your second example, when I make the `CenterCenterCenter` part bigger it causes `RightRightRight` to wrap _below_ `CenterCenterCenter` (in both SO Snippet and your original JSFiddle link) which is contrary to what you said: "If you need the middle item to wrap beneath the `.right` item..." - can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You're quite right, @Dai. I don't know how that's stood for so long, but I've updated the code to wrap the center under the right in example 2 now. Thanks

Comment: @Red I added those checkboxes because the SO snippet window can’t be shrunk below ~500px making it impossible to force a wrap to see the effect-in-question - if the checkboxes weren’t working for you it means you’re using an old web-browser that doesn’t support CSS `:has()` - all major browsers support it: https://caniuse.com/css-has (update: Hm, except Firefox - I thought Firefox did support it by now…)

Comment: Hi @Dai, in the jsFiddle window you can grab the separator to the left of the bottom right window and resize to any size within the main window to test responsiveness

Comment: @Red [Use of JSFiddle is discouraged vs. SO's self-hosted snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358212/how-do-i-include-code-for-jsfiddle) - JSFiddle won't be around forever so posted answers with only JSFiddle links will be broken.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `flex-flow:column wrap;` when you want to use `flex-flow: row wrap`. And your divs are out of order—you want the `.center` div to be last. Flexbox orders divs based on ascending values.

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.block{
  height: 50px;
}

.left{
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  order: 1;
}

.center{
  width: 60%;
  background-color: green;
  order: 2;
}

.right{
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  order: 3;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  #wrapper{
    flex-flow: row wrap; 
    height: 100px;
  }
  .center {
    width: 100%;
    order: 3;
  }
  .right {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .left{
    width: 50%;
    order: 1;
   
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="block left">Left</div>
    <div class="block center">Center</div>
    <div class="block right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I upvote you because I cannot accept both answers but both answers helped to me :)