# Choosing wrap elements in Xamarin's Flex Layout

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am essentially trying to get the Xamarin FlexLayout version of the answer given to this css question: [Flexbox: move middle element to the next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927483)

I have a fairly simple `Xamarin Forms UI` which has three elements in a horizontal line. Depending on the screen width available, I need the middle of these elements to wrap below to the next vertical line.

I know it's possible to fall back to the css answer, but I'm looking for a native solution.

**Ample width**

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────┐
|                WRAPPER                 |
|   ┌─────────┬───────────┬──────────┐   |
|   |  LEFT   |   CENTER  |   RIGHT  |   |
|   |         |           |          |   |
|   └─────────┴───────────┴──────────┘   |
└────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

**Limited Width**

```
┌────────────────────────┐
|        WRAPPER         |
|  ┌────────┬─────────┐  |
|  |  LEFT  |  RIGHT  |  |
|  |        |         |  |
|  └────────┴─────────┘  |
|  ┌──────────────────┐  |
|  |      CENTER      |  |
|  |                  |  |
|  └──────────────────┘  |
|                        |
└────────────────────────┘
```

I can't obviously see any way to do it, though logically it might be possible to adjust `FlexLayout.Order="x"` for the center element once the wrap occurs, but I'm not sure how to trigger on that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the following code

```
<FlexLayout  AlignContent="Center"  JustifyContent="Center"  Wrap="Wrap" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  >


    <Label Text="Left"
               HeightRequest="50"
               FontSize="Large"
               WidthRequest="150"
               BackgroundColor="Gray"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"

               FlexLayout.Order="1"
               />

    <Label Text="Center"
               FontSize="Large"
               HeightRequest="50"
               WidthRequest="300"
               BackgroundColor="Red"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"

               FlexLayout.Order="3"
              />

    <Label Text="Right"
               FontSize="Large"
               WidthRequest="150"
               BackgroundColor="Gray"
               HeightRequest="50"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               FlexLayout.Order="2"
              />

</FlexLayout>
```

For more details and usage of **FlexLayout** you could refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.flexlayout?view=xamarin-forms

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but while that works for narrow widths it positions the Center box in the wrong place for larger widths:`[ Left ] [ Right ] [ Center ]`

Comment: Because I set the width of label as static value just for demo, so it will be an expected result . You need to set the width of label as you need  .

Comment: It will warp when the width of screen smaller than the width of three labels .

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something then, I get the following when I set the three WidthRequest values from your example to "50" (for example): https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiFOTk4n4xTsgZZKXGkXa-dHFdd5uQ?e=1FKauJ

Comment: Because the value of width is to small . as I said , it will warp when the width of screen smaller than the width of three labels .

Comment: But when it's not wrapped it should look like this: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiFOTk4n4xTsgZZLtRPJ3jVKIlbbjA?e=pgKt5y

Comment: You could set the value of `FlexLayout.Order` in different size of screen like css .

Comment: ok thanks, so I can add this in to something like Page.OnSizeAllocated (or Parent.OnSizeAllocated).

Answer (score 1):

Working now. For anyone else that needs it, following Lucas Zhang's guide I named the middle label and handled it in the code like this:

```css
<Label  x:Name="MiddleLabel"
        BackgroundColor="Red"
        FlexLayout.Order="2"
        FontSize="Large"
        HeightRequest="50"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        Text="Center"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
        WidthRequest="150" />
```

```css
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height) {
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

            if (width >= height)
            {
                FlexLayout.SetOrder(MiddleLabel, 2);
            }
            else
            {
                FlexLayout.SetOrder(MiddleLabel, 4);

            }
        }
```